# Graphs and Dynkin-diagrams in Latex

Tags: graphs

Please, if anyone knows about latex, can help me drawing Dynkins diagrams and also the graphs in chapter 13 of the book "Introduction to Lie algebras"?
I wrote what Benjamin McKay gave me, as in below but it does not work.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\begin{document}
Page 56:
\pgfkeys{/Dynkin diagram,arrows=false}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
A_1 \times A_1 & \dynkin{A}{1}\dynkin{A}{1}\\
A_2                     & \dynkin{A}{2}\\
B_2                     & \dynkin{B}{2}\\
G_2                     & \dynkin{G}{2} 
\end{array}
\]

Page 57:
\pgfkeys{/Dynkin diagram,arrows=true}
\[
\begin{array}{cc}
B_2                     & \dynkin{B}{2}\\
G_2                     & \dynkin{G}{2} 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works for me (after marking the code as such) when compiling it with `pdflatex`. If it really does not work for you, then there might be something wrong with your LaTeX installation.

Comment: There is another way to draw Dynkin diagrams and graphs because it didn't work for me, even if i download this packages in CTAN.

Comment: You should use your package manager to install the package, not download packages by hand. Doing it with another package does not solve your problems on the long run.

Comment: Ok. Thank you- Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens? Do you get an error (which one)? Is the output wrong? It works fine for me as well, with a fairly up to date TeX Live 2019.

Comment: Me i use texmaker and it didn't work for me because i have a missing packages i must download them but i didn't find package manager.

Comment: Finally it works. Now how can i change the size of the Graphs and also give names for the vertices Like in chapter 13 of the book "Introduction to Lie algebras?